# intel tel input error : invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, validation, encoding, character-encoding, intl

im using intl tel input plugin for number validation, when i set it up locally it works fine, but when i upload it to my hosting it gives me the error linked in the image below
**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-ZÃ€-Ã¿Ð°-ÑÐ-Ð¯ ]$/: Range out of order in character class"**

keep in mind that i have been using it for months and i have never faced this issue, and to clear stuff even more i made sure to disable all my other plugins to make sure theres no interference in anyway or shape, but im still facing this issue

[image]

Comment: It is an issue with UTF8